# Get object location Java2D (not corner)

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

How do I get JLabel location instead of top left x/y location of the object in Java?

Comment: What do you mean when you say object location? Memory location? Screen location that's not x/y?

Comment: If you do a JLabel.getX it returns the top left corner of the object; I don't want that.

Comment: What do you want? The middle? Bottom right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JLabel.getBounds()`. With that `Rectangle` you can find whatever notion of location it is you're looking for. You can do similar things with `JLabel.getLocation()` followed by `JLabel.getWidth()` and `JLabel.getHeight()`.

`JLabel.getVisibleRect()` is also handy in some cases. If you are actually looking to find the location relative to a coordinate system other than the `JLabel`'s parent, you can use `SwingUtilities` to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the X&Y by the getLocation(), then the getSize() tells you how big it is.

You can do the math to figure out the bottom right and middle. (x + width = left edge, y + height = bottom edge.)